# Display row values as column header

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have a `select` statement

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLENAME 
 WHERE WORKERNAME = 'A'
   AND DATE = '12/17/2014'
```

The output will be:

```
FREE | USED | DATE      | WORKERNAME
------------------------------------
  1  |  0   |12/17/2014 | A
  1  |  0   |12/17/2014 | A      
  1  |  0   |12/17/2014 | A
```

I need to have an output where outputs for `DATE` and `WORKERNAME` will be column header that will look like:

```
    A
----------
12/17/2014
----------
FREE | USED
----------
1    | 0
1    | 0
1    | 0
```

Can someone suggest how this could be achieved using an oracle SQL or PL/SQL?

Comment: What's the logic of multi line header name? and how result have 4 rows while question have only 3?

Comment: What version of Oracle? Is it 9i, 10G, 11G (R1 or R2), or 12C

Comment: I edited the question and removed the 4th row. That is the output that I need to display.

Comment: @realspirituals oracle10g

Comment: OK. There is a pivot operator in 11G and above which is too easy,  but in your case, you should try column to row conversion using aggregate functions. Post what you have tried so far

Comment: Why is there close vote for this???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would not be that elegant to produce the output you are after using pure SQL or even PL/SQL. It would be better if you let a client do the work. Depending on how you want to present your final output to an end user your choices are ranging from simple SQL*PLUS to a more sophisticated reporting tools. Here is a simple example of how you can produce that output using SQL*PLUS:

```
clear screen;

column workername new_value worker_name;
column date1 new_value d1;
column workername noprint;
column date1 noprint;
set linesize 15;
column free format a7;
column used format a7;
ttitle center worker_name skip 1 -
center '------------' skip 1 -
center d1 skip 1 -
center '------------' skip 1;
set colsep '|'

/* sample of data from your question */
with t1(free, used, date1, workername) as(
   select 1, 0, date '2014-12-17', 'A' from dual union all
   select 1, 0, date '2014-12-17', 'A' from dual union all
   select 1, 0, date '2014-12-17', 'A' from dual
)
select to_char(free) as free
     , to_char(used) as used
     , to_char(date1, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as date1
     , workername
  from t1
 where workername = 'A'
   and date1 = date '2014-12-17';
```

Result:

```
       A       
  ------------ 
   12/17/2014   
  ------------ 
 FREE   |USED   
 -------|-------
 1      |0      
 1      |0      
 1      |0
```

If there is a need to produce a report that includes different `workernames` or/and different `date`, the `break on` SQL*PLUS command can be used to break report on a specific column or a combination of columns. For example:

```
column workername new_value worker_name;
column date1 new_value d1;
column workername noprint;
column date1 noprint;
set linesize 15;
column free format a7;
column used format a7;
ttitle center worker_name skip 1 -
center '------------' skip 1 -
center d1 skip 1 -
center '------------' skip 1;
set colsep '|'
break on worker_name skip page on date1 skip page;

/* sample of data  */
with t1(free, used, date1, workername) as(
   select 1, 0, date '2014-12-17', 'A' from dual union all
   select 1, 0, date '2014-11-17', 'A' from dual union all
   select 1, 0, date '2014-12-17', 'A' from dual union all
   select 1, 0, date '2014-11-17', 'B' from dual
)
select to_char(free) as free
     , to_char(used) as used
     , to_char(date1, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as date1
     , workername
  from t1
 order by workername, date1;
```

Result:

```
       A       
  ------------ 
   11/17/2014  
  ------------ 
FREE   |USED   
-------|-------
1      |0      

       A       
  ------------ 
   12/17/2014  
  ------------ 
FREE   |USED   
-------|-------
1      |0      
1      |0      

       B       
  ------------ 
   11/17/2014  
  ------------ 
FREE   |USED   
-------|-------
1      |0
```

Here is the [SQL*PLUS user's guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/toc.htm) where you can find detailed information on any command that's been used in the above examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
TTITLE LEFT 'Manager: ' MGRVAR SKIP 2
BREAK ON MANAGER_ID SKIP PAGE
BTITLE OFF


SELECT MANAGER_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID, LAST_NAME, SALARY
FROM EMP_DETAILS_VIEW
WHERE MANAGER_ID IN (101, 201)
ORDER BY MANAGER_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID;


Manager:       101

DEPARTMENT_ID LAST_NAME                     SALARY
------------- ------------------------- ----------
           10 Whalen                          4400
           40 Mavris                          6500
           70 Baer                           10000
          100 Greenberg                      12000
          110 Higgins                        12000

Manager:       201

DEPARTMENT_ID LAST_NAME                     SALARY
------------- ------------------------- ----------
           20 Fay                             6000

6 rows selected.
```

See if something like this helps you.

Comment: -1 ... Downvoting since it is neither has any useful snippets nor any explanation

Comment: it has he cab display date in that format where it has manager simple

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using pivot would be useful for you.

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@colsName AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(WORKERNAME +'_'+convert(varchar(50),[DATE]) +'_'+c.col) 
                  from TRY
                  cross apply 
                  (
                    select 'FREE' col
                    union all
                    select 'USED'
                  ) c
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
select @colsName 
= STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + QUOTENAME(WORKERNAME +'_'+convert(varchar(50),[DATE])+'_'+c.col) 
           +' as ['
           + WORKERNAME + case when c.col = 'FREE' then '_'+convert(varchar(50),[DATE])+'_FREE]' else '_'+convert(varchar(50),[DATE])+'_USED]' end
         from TRY
         cross apply 
         (
            select 'FREE' col
            union all
            select 'USED'

         ) c
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ID, ' + @colsName + ' 
 from 
 (
  select 
    ID, 
    WORKERNAME +''_''+convert(varchar(50),[DATE]) +''_''+col col, 
    value
  from
  (
    select ID, 
      WORKERNAME, 
      date,
    cast(FREE as numeric(10, 2)) FREE,
  cast(USED as numeric(10, 2)) USED
    from TRY
  ) src
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (FREE, USED)
  ) unpiv
 ) s
 pivot 
 (
   sum(value)
   for col in (' + @cols + ')
 ) p 
 order by ID'

execute(@query)
```

Comment: PIVOT is not introduced in 10G.